# Spark Structural Streaming with Confluent Cloud Kafka connectivity issue

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am writing a Spark structured streaming application in PySpark to read data from Kafka in Confluent Cloud. The documentation for the spark `readstream()` function is too shallow and didn't specify much on the optional parameter part especially on the auth mechanism part. I am not sure what parameter goes wrong and crash the connectivity. Can anyone have experience in Spark help me to start this connection?

**Required Parameter**

> ```
> > Consumer({'bootstrap.servers':
> > 'cluster.gcp.confluent.cloud:9092',
> >               'sasl.username':'xxx',
> >               'sasl.password':  'xxx',
> >               'sasl.mechanisms': 'PLAIN',
> >               'security.protocol': 'SASL_SSL',
> >     'group.id': 'python_example_group_1',
> >     'auto.offset.reset': 'earliest' })
> ```

Here is my pyspark code:

```
df = spark \
  .readStream \
  .format("kafka") \
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "cluster.gcp.confluent.cloud:9092") \
  .option("subscribe", "test-topic") \
  .option("kafka.sasl.mechanisms", "PLAIN")\
  .option("kafka.security.protocol", "SASL_SSL")\
  .option("kafka.sasl.username","xxx")\
  .option("kafka.sasl.password", "xxx")\
  .option("startingOffsets", "latest")\
  .option("kafka.group.id", "python_example_group_1")\
  .load()
display(df)
```

However, I keep getting an error:

> kafkashaded.org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to
>   construct kafka consumer

**DataBrick Notebook**- for testing

https://databricks-prod-cloudfront.cloud.databricks.com/public/4027ec902e239c93eaaa8714f173bcfc/4673082066872014/3543014086288496/1802788104169533/latest.html

**Documentation**

https://home.apache.org/~pwendell/spark-nightly/spark-branch-2.0-docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html

Comment: Have you tried using the other consumer? https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.1/streaming-kafka-0-10-integration.html#ssl--tls

Comment: @cricket_007, not yet, as one of the requirements is stream-stream joining which only supported by structural streaming. Direct Stream has limitations in joining two streams. Hence, this is why i need to use `readStream()`. Online resource only foucs more in DStream. Quite difficult to looks for anwser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to specified `kafka.sasl.jaas.config` to add the username and password for the Confluent Kafka SASL-SSL auth method. Its parameter looks a bit odd, but it's working.

```
df = spark \
      .readStream \
      .format("kafka") \
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "pkc-43n10.us-central1.gcp.confluent.cloud:9092") \
      .option("subscribe", "wallet_txn_log") \
      .option("startingOffsets", "earliest") \
      .option("kafka.security.protocol","SASL_SSL") \
      .option("kafka.sasl.mechanism", "PLAIN") \
      .option("kafka.sasl.jaas.config", """kafkashaded.org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="xxx" password="xxx";""").load()
display(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

This error indicates that JAAS configuration is not visible to your Kafka consumer. To solve this issue include JASS based on the follow steps:

**Step01: Create a file for below JAAS file** : /home/jass/path

```
KafkaClient {
     com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
     useTicketCache=true
     renewTicket=true
     serviceName="kafka";
     };
```

Step02: Call that JASS file path in spark-submit based on the below conf parameter .

```
--conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/home/jass/path"
```

**Full spark-submit command :**

```
/usr/hdp/2.6.1.0-129/spark2/bin/spark-submit --packages com.databricks:spark-avro_2.11:3.2.0,org.apache.spark:spark-avro_2.11:2.4.0,org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.2.0 --conf spark.ui.port=4055 --files /home/jass/path,/home/bdpda/bdpda.headless.keytab --conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/home/jass/path" --conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/home/jass/path" pysparkstructurestreaming.py
```

**Pyspark Structured streaming sample code :**

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
import time

#  Spark Streaming context :

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('PythonStreamingDirectKafkaWordCount').getOrCreate()
sc = spark.sparkContext
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 20)

#  Kafka Topic Details :

KAFKA_TOPIC_NAME_CONS = "topic_name"
KAFKA_OUTPUT_TOPIC_NAME_CONS = "topic_to_hdfs"
KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONS = 'kafka_server:9093'

#  Creating  readstream DataFrame :

df = spark.readStream \
     .format("kafka") \
     .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONS) \
     .option("subscribe", KAFKA_TOPIC_NAME_CONS) \
     .option("startingOffsets", "earliest") \
     .option("kafka.security.protocol","SASL_SSL")\
     .option("kafka.client.id" ,"Clinet_id")\
     .option("kafka.sasl.kerberos.service.name","kafka")\
     .option("kafka.ssl.truststore.location", "/home/path/kafka_trust.jks") \
     .option("kafka.ssl.truststore.password", "password_rd") \
     .option("kafka.sasl.kerberos.keytab","/home/path.keytab") \
     .option("kafka.sasl.kerberos.principal","path") \
     .load()

df1 = df.selectExpr( "CAST(value AS STRING)")

#  Creating  Writestream DataFrame :

df1.writeStream \
   .option("path","target_directory") \
   .format("csv") \
   .option("checkpointLocation","chkpint_directory") \
   .outputMode("append") \
   .start()

ssc.awaitTermination()
```

Comment: Thanks for your well-edited answer. It works actually in Spark Cluster.

For the `spark-shell` usecase, we might need to add `--driver-java-options "-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/home/jass/path" `